# Поиск процесса nginx

Tags: php, nginx

Запущено много процессов с одного скрипта trade.php с разными параметрами
Как проверить есть ли такой процесс по названию с нужными параметрами?
ps ax|grep trades.php|grep -v grep пробовал так, но не могу указать параметры.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте команду [pgrep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep): `pgrep -f "trade.php <param1> <param2>"`